# Only able to get wired internet connection when running 14.04 from disc, not when installed

Tags: wired

After re-installing 14.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1520 laptop I found that I could no longer get a wired internet connection. I vaguely recall that I had a problem connecting when I first installed 14.04 months ago but I don't recall what I did to correct it. Note that if I try the run the OS from disc I have no problems.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem I got mine fixed with the advice from the following thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300380&p=13379360#post13379360